# Issues putting up a high score for my snake game

Tags: python

```
def reader():
     myfile = open("scores.txt","r")
     pre = myfile.readlines()

     for line in pre :

          x = line.split(",")
          a = x[0]
          b = x[1]
          c = len(b)-1c
          b = b[0:c]
          highest[a] = b
```

I have succeeded in writing the scores to a file and I intend to read the file into a dic, but it's not working. I'm getting:

```
   error: IndexError: list index out of range
```

How do I fix it?
       anymore

Comment: pls provide the exact code that gives you the error. you can also put in print statements to see where the index error is produced.

Comment: and i still get an AssertionError but thanks a lot i am greatful

Comment: highest = {}
def reader():
    myfile = open("scores.txt","r")
    pre = myfile.readlines()
    print(pre)
    for line in pre :
        
        x = line.split(",")
        assert len(x) == 1
        a = x[0]
        b = x[1]
        # c = len(b)-1
        # b = b[0:c]
        highest[a] = b
        print(line)
        print(x[1])

Comment: Anihs, add your code to your original question - it's easier to read there. :)

Comment: What is the line that gives the error? Is it `a = x[0]`/`b = x[1]`? If so, check your file for empty lines or lines without commas. Is it `highest[a] = b`? If so, please show us how `highest` is initialized.

Comment: Oh, and I see that the code you posted in the comment is not the same that you put in the question.

Comment: its x[1] and my files actually has empty lines but i dont know ho wto fix that

Comment: i want to write the scores into the files in different lines so trying to read it back into the highest = {} dictionary gives the error at b = x[1]

Comment: yes the codes are different someone already helped with an answer so i applied it and got another error and i was just trying to show him i already did what he asked me to do

Comment: please edit the question and: 1. include the most recent code; 2. include the full traceback for the error you are getting now

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - index out of range error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34744959/python-index-out-of-range-error)