# Python - index out of range error

Tags: python

This is my most recent code:

```
highest = {}
def reader():
    myfile = open("scores.txt","r")
    pre = myfile.readlines()

    print(pre)


    for line in pre :
       print(line)
       x = line.split(",")

       a = x[0]

       b = x[1]

       c = len(b)-1
       b = b[0:c]

       highest[a] = b
```

And this is the Traceback error message in full:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:/Python34/my boto snaky/snaky.py", line 568, in gameLoop
        reader()
        File "C:/Python34/my boto snaky/snaky.py", line 531, in reader
        b = x[1]
        IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Some of your lines in scores.txt don't have a comma (',') in them.
Also, use a better title.

Comment: Is that really the most descriptive title you could come up with?

Comment: it says the error. "list index out of range". You either dont have commas in some of your lines or missing data.

Comment: actually they do have commas i think the issue is the empty lines in between each scores but i really don't know how to fix that

Comment: @AnihsEmma: `"actually they do have commas"` and `"the issue is the empty lines"` are mutually exclusive statements.  An empty line wouldn't have commas, hence the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of your lines in scores.txt don't have a comma. You can check for those :

```
if len(x) == 1 : #there is no comma
    continue #ignore line and go to the next one
```

This code would ignore the lines without a comma. Place it just after computing x = line.split(',') .

Same if you just want to skip empty lines :

```
if line.strip() == '': #remove whitespace then check if line is empty
    continue
```